# jQuery loop steps and add html

Tags: jquery, loops

Is there a way to simplify the code below? The code counts down as each div is dropped into a container. I have only posted the section of code I would like to simplify. I appreciate any guidance in this.

```
 if (count === 0) {
        $(".ernie").remove();
        $("#choices").append("<p class='ernie gone sr-only'>That was the last question</p>");
    }
    if (count === 1) {
        $(".ernie").remove();
        $("#choices").append("<p class='ernie sr-only'>There is 1 more question to select</p>");
    }
    if (count === 2) {
        $(".ernie").remove();
        $("#choices").append("<p class='ernie sr-only'>There are 2 questions to select</p>");
    }
    if (count === 3) {
        $(".ernie").remove();
        $("#choices").append("<p class='ernie sr-only'>There are 3 questions to select</p>");
    }
    if (count === 4) {
        $(".ernie").remove();
        $("#choices").append("<p class='ernie sr-only'>There are 4 questions to select</p>");
    }
    if (count === 5) {
        $(".ernie").remove();
        $("#choices").append("<p class='ernie sr-only'>There are 5 questions to select</p>");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var message = "";
message = (count === 0) ? 'That was the last question' : (count === 1 ? 'There is 1 more question to select' : 'There are '+ count +' questions to select');     
$(".ernie").remove();
$("#choices").append("<p class='ernie gone sr-only'>"+message+"</p>");
```

Comment: Once check all strings. Your will generate for more than 1 count.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".ernie").remove();
if (count) {
    $("#choices").append("<p class='ernie sr-only'>There " + (count > 1 ? "are" : "is") + " " + count + " more question" + (count > 1 ? "s" : "") + " to select</p>");
} else {
    $("#choices").append("<p class='ernie gone sr-only'>That was the last question</p>");
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x7t7z7vb/)

Comment: Your code doesn't generate 'are' string for more than 1 count.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone for the quick responses and the help. This is really helpful.

Comment: I have had to un-accept the answer unfortunately as there is an error in the script. Error generated in testing "Expected ')' and instead saw 'count'".

Comment: It s working fine for me, you can check here https://jsfiddle.net/x7t7z7vb/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `switch` statement instead, and also remove `.ernie` before your `if` statement (you're just going to remove it anyway).

You can also set the text to append to `#choices`, rather than typing it out every time, and append on `count`'s value.

```
var text = "<p class='ernie sr-only'>There " + (count > 1 ? "are " : "is ") + count + " more question to select</p>";

$(".ernie").remove(); // remove ernie anyway
switch(count) {
    case 1: // if count is equal to 1
        $("#choices").append("<p class='ernie gone sr-only'>That was the last question</p>");
       break; 
    case 2: // if count is equal to 2
        $("#choices").append(text);
        break;
    // and so on...
    deafault: // if count is not equal to any of the above numbers
        void(0); // javascript for do nothing
        break;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your code doesn't generate for more than one count.

Comment: @VforVendetta what do you mean?

Comment: There is 1 more question to select, There are 2 questions to select There are two different strings to generate. Do you get me ?

Comment: @VforVendetta no I do not... It works perfectly on my end

Comment: Your string is generating, "There is 1 more question to select" for count 1, and "There is 2 more question to select" for count 2 also. For more clarification, once go through question once, HINT : 'is', 'are'

Comment: @VforVendetta ah, got ya! fixed :-)

Answer (score 0):

Following is more simple answer. You have to remove .element with .ernie always, so make that common then for zero you have "last" to be added, for others it's just the count. So here is your answer.

```
$(".ernie").remove();
if(count === 0){
    $("#choices").append("<p class='ernie gone sr-only'>That was the last question</p>");
}else if(count === 1){
    $("#choices").append("<p class='ernie sr-only'>There is 1 more question to select</p>");
}
else if(typeof count === "number" ) {
    $("#choices").append("<p class='ernie sr-only'>There are " + count + " questions to select</p>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below optimized snippet.

```
if(count !== ""){
    $(".ernie").remove();
    var msg = "";
    if(count===0){
        msg = "That was the last question";
    }else if(count===1){
        msg = "There is 1 more question to select";
    }else{
        msg = "There are "+count+" questions to select";
    }
    $("#choices").append("<p class='ernie gone sr-only'>"+msg+"</p>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**it may be helpful**

```
if (count === 0 || count === 1 || count === 2 || count === 3 || count === 4 || count === 5) {
    append(count)
}


countArray = ['That was the last question','There is 1 more question to select','There are 2 questions to select','There are 3 questions to select','There are 4 questions to select','There are 5 questions to select']

function append(count){
     $(".ernie").remove();
     $("#choices").append('<p class="ernie gone sr-only">'+countArray[count]+'</p>');
}
```